# Save a list of object types in a variable

Tags: vb.net

I want to save a list of object types into a variable.

For example something like this

```
Dim allowedTypes As New List(Of Type)
allowedTypes.Add(TextBox)
```

The above produces an error, however I need to save a list of object types in this list so that I could compare the allowedTypes when creating elements dynamically via a loop.

Is this possible in Vb.Net (Any alternative suggestions are welcome).

Comment: TextBox is a type and cannot be used in an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tay4kywk.aspx) to get `Type` object for the specified type :

```
Dim allowedTypes As New List(Of Type)
allowedTypes.Add(GetType(TextBox))
```

Comment: Error is gone. I will check the entire thing & accept the answer.. Thanks..!

Comment: Just my luck to be too slow =(

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the `GetType` method, as in:

```
Dim allowedTypes as new List(Of Type)
allowedTypes.Add(GetType(TextBox))
```